# получить конкретные данные из Array

Tags: javascript

столкнулся со сложностью которую не могу решить=/

есть настройки языка по странам:

```
"LANGUAGE": {
"OPTIONS": ["en-US" , "rus-RU" , "zh-CN" , "fi-FI"],
"FALLBACK": "en-US"
```

начало кода по получению значния:

```
var regionalCod = Facade.config.LANGUAGE.OPTIONS,
 change_regionalCod = regionalCod, // здесь пытался извлечь значения через .toString().split("-")[1]
 change_regionalCodLow = change_regionalCod, // здесь менял формат .toLowerCase()
 regionalCod = change_regionalCodLow;

console.log(regionalCod);
```

консоль выдает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно что бы выдавала: us, ru, cn, fi

тоесть брало только код страны написанный большими буквами после тире, меняло на маленький формат и возвращало обратно

как :   ["us" , "ru" , "cn" , "fi"] или  просто "us" , "ru" , "cn" , "fi"

желательно с возможностью потом выцепить любое из значений по желанию...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь можно применить [функцию `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var regionalCod = Facade.config.LANGUAGE.OPTIONS.map(function(language){
    return language.split('-')[1].toLowerCase();
})
```

Пример:

```js
var OPTIONS = ["en-US", "rus-RU", "zh-CN", "fi-FI"];
document.write('<div>' + JSON.stringify(OPTIONS) + '</div>');
var regionalCod = OPTIONS.map(function(language) {
  return language.split('-')[1].toLowerCase();
});
document.write('<div>' + JSON.stringify(regionalCod) + '</div>');
```